# Packing and compressing resource data

Tags: c++, game-engine, zlib

I try to pack and compress game client resource data using zlib. If I compress the data, it will reduce Disk I/O as reduced file size but it increases CPU usage when uncompress.

**Question1**

if a resource used for rendering is compressed, processing (rendering and uncompressing) uses CPU, so i think it seems to be rather slow, is it right?

If no compression, Disk I/O has not changed and an additional CPU usage does not occur. And if you read only a portion of the file, DISK I/O can be reduced by using the CreateFileMapping(), MapViewOfFile() functions.

**Question2**

In the case of the resource, such as uncompressed image(for example tga, not png) when we have to read whole file (ex. image file), we can't get adventage of CreateFileMapping(), MapViewOfFile(), so i think compressing resource is better, how do you think?

**Question3**

What do you think about compressing resource data when packing?

Answer (score 5):

Resources for games are not only packed to reduce size, but also to reduce the number of seeks by collapsing many small files into one, which matters a lot more than the size on disk. A single unnecessary seek on a conventional hard disk costs as much time as reading a gigabyte of data. Even if your "compression" consists of only concatenating small files together, you already gain performance.
As a small bonus, having resources packed in an archive somewhat obscures them from computer unsavy people, deterring them from modifying game assets (though admittedly, this is not a very big hurdle!).

**Q1:** Depending on what compression algorithm you use, you can easily get upwards of 1 GB/s decompression (close to 2 GB/s with a fast CPU). Sequential disk I/O is still around 300-400 MB/s maximum even on solid state (and usually less). Random access disk I/O is 5-20 times slower, depending on the disk and the access pattern.
On the other hand, you can get as little as a few dozen kilobytes per second in decompression speed if you choose a slow algorithm, which is much worse than just loading more data from disk. The secret is to choose an algorithm that compresses reasonably  well (not perfectly, just reasonably) and runs at good decompression speed. Compression speed usually does not matter, since this is done offline once. Candidate algorithms are for example LZF, Snappy, or LZ4.
File mapping can generally be used regardless of whether the contents are compressed. Also, filemapping is **not** only an advantage for very small portions, on the contrary. The larger your reads, the more advantageous it becomes (very small views may actually be faster using conventional reads).

**Q2:** Uncompressed images do not normally occur in a game. Most of the time you will want to use DXT compression, not so much to reduce disk I/O but to reduce memory and PCIe bandwidth requirements and GPU memory consumption. DXT is a very poor compression, but it works in hardware and has an exactly predictable compression ratio. You can compress DXT-compressed textures again with a conventional general-purpose compressor (with varying rates, depending on what compressor you used, there are some that are especially optimized for that purpose).

**Q3:** Packing resources is definitively advisable for any non-trivial game.